# Forbidden error in server not in local host for huge data

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, http-status-code-404

I have an application which allows users to share there notes.

The front end is written in php and back end is driven by mysql database. The front end has an edit section, which is using Ueditor (web based editor). The problem is that if I am trying to edit small amount of data on the server it will work, but if I am trying to edit huge amount of data it will not work and shows this error.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /editnotes.php on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Additionally it is working perfectly alright in local host.

Comment: Might be regarding file permission 7-7-7 : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

Comment: It is working perfectly alright for small amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

The `ErrorDocument` directive, when supplied a local URL path, expects the path to be fully qualified from the `DocumentRoot`.

Have this in your `.htaccess` file

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errorpagedir/403page.html
```

`/errorpagedir/403page.html` is your 403 error page.

Comment: can you give me more details to fix this issue?.